# Summary Fields triggers settings not enabled

Tags: summaryfields, trigger

On the extensions admin screen I see

[image]

I tried following [this solution](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/17799/triggers-for-summary-fields-disappeared) but rebuilding triggers had no effect.

How do I get the triggers to be enabled? The cron job *Call SumFields.Gendata API* says it is successful and runs every hour.

> Parameters parsed (and passed to API method): 
>   a:1:{s:7:"version";i:3;}
>
> Full message:  Finished execution of Call SumFields.Gendata API with
>   result: Success (a:1:{i:0;s:89:"Original Status: scheduled:2020-05-04
>   15:33:23, New Status: scheduled:2020-05-04 15:37:48";})

That is the only cron job I see.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Andy, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I've created this issue on github: https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.sumfields/issues/83

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the slow response - I am just now seeing this question.

The status *should* be: "Setting changes were saved on 2020-05-04, data calculation will be performed on every cron run." I'm not sure why that confusing message is displayed instead. Do you have the summary fields cron job enabled? If not, that could be the problem. When the summary fields cron job runs, it should create the triggers and calculate as needed.

For testing, you could also try updating the settings manually. In other words, where it says "When should these changes be applied?" - select "When I submit this form". Then click the save button.

If the status still says the triggers are not created, trying de-selecting one of the fields in the configuration and saving. Then, re-select and save again (summary fields pays attention to whether there are any changes in the list of selected fields and will only update the triggers if there is a change).

Comment: I've done these steps on 5.0.0. The "Status of current settings" and "Data update method: Cron Job" are correct. but no triggers for Triggers for civicrm_contribution or Triggers for civicrm_participant:  which I am using are enabled. 

What are the findings of this extension on a large db of around 800K records? I've been very selective and using the simplified fields for performance considerations.

Comment: The Scheduled job says e.g. Finished execution of Call SumFields.Gendata API with result: Success (a:1:{i:0;s:89:"Original Status: scheduled:2021-04-23 06:32:07, New Status: scheduled:2021-04-23 07:47:03";})

Comment: No triggers should be enabled if your data update method is "When the cron job runs". Triggers are only enabled if the update method is "instantly".